# SharePoint Online Infopath "This content cannot be displayed in a frame"

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I have developed a SharePoint InfoPath form to capture contact details of an end users on my public facing SharePoint Online system. On SharePoint Online it works without problem if I have logged in using my credentials, but if I try to hit the URL with anonymous user it shows an error

> This content cannot be displayed in a frame.

```
https://manu-public.sharepoint.com/Pages/ContactUs.aspx
```

[image: Not Working: If not logged in]

[image: Working: If logged in]

Comment: does your aspx Page contain a Webpart?

Comment: Yes it's a  Page viewer webpart pointing to new item page of the list on the same site.

Comment: have you checked the permissions for anonymous users to access this form?  are you able to open the new item page anonymously?

Comment: Nope.. New item form is asking for credentials https://manu-public.sharepoint.com/Lists/ContactUs/Item/newifs.aspx

Comment: so maybe that is your problem?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a cross domain issue

Open the console and check the below error

```
Refused to display 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1%2E0&rpsnv=4&ct=1435…m%2F%5Fforms%2Fdefault%2Easpx%3Fapr%3D1&lc=1033&id=500046&guests=1&IsDlg=1' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
```

Check more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dd548514.aspx)

Comment: I think it can not be a cross domain issue. As the page displays properly if i have logged in using my credentials.